# Enviar un modelo a ActionResult por ajax MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.Net MVC y quiero implementar Ajax para una proceso, el problema es que al momento de enviar un modelo al servidor este llega nulo, pero con otras variables que le pase esta si pasan correctas.

> Codigo de la vista

```
var CollectionViewModelJs = '@Model';
$(function () {

    $("#btnajax").click(function () {
        swal.showLoading();
        $("#TableMemories").empty();
        var url = "@Url.Action("DepositMethod","DescriptiveMemories")";

        var datos = "Hola";
        var data = { CollectionViewModel: CollectionViewModelJs};


        $.post(url, data).done(function (data) {

            $("#TableMemories").append(data);
            swal.close();
        }).fail("");

    });
});
```

Código de mi controlador, he intentado usar con Bind pero sigue llegando nulo incluso una lista pero aun asi sigue llegando nulo, CollectionViewModel es el modelo.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DepositMethod(CollectionViewModel CollectionViewModel, String datos)
        {

        var cv = db.DescriptiveMemories.Where(row => row.Folio == 18516).ToList();
        int s = cv.Count();
        var model = new CollectionViewModel();
        model.DescriptiveMemories = cv.ToList();
        model.DescriptiveMemories[0].FolioInvoice = "Folio desde ajax";
        return PartialView("_CollectionPartial", model);
    }
```

Clase CollectionViewModel

```
public class CollectionViewModel
    {
        public List<DescriptiveMemory> DescriptiveMemories { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fecha inicial")]
        public DateTime? Startdate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fecha final")]
        public DateTime? Enddate { get; set; }

        public CollectionViewModel()
        {
            DescriptiveMemories = new List<DescriptiveMemory>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas recibiendo null en el backend porque NetCore o Net no entiende el objeto que le estas enviando. Estas mandando `{ CollectionViewModel: CollectionViewModelJs }` y el backend esta esperando `CollectionViewModel` no es lo mismo y por eso da null.

En vez de esto

`var data = { CollectionViewModel: CollectionViewModelJs};`

Deberias hacer esto

  `var data = CollectionViewModelJs;`

Pero para estar más seguro necesitaria que muestres la clase `CollectionViewModel`

Comment: Funciono pero ahora me llega vacio, o sea no trea los datos que yo quiero, ahora te mando la clase

Comment: Ya agregue la clase, la lista de DescriptiveMemories, es la que necesito, pero este llega vacia

Comment: Lo que tengo es una tabla donde carga uno lista de datos y esa misma quiero enviarla por ajax a mi servidor, si lo hago con metodo normal si llega pero con ajax no

Comment: Si te funcionó marca la respuesta como correcta ;) please

Comment: Para ayudarte un poco mas. Cuando tu mandas un request al servidor. Lo que mandas no es una clase. Estas mandando un json. El parser de net necesita que la clase que le indicas en la entrada de tu controlador coincida con los pares de llaves valor que estan en tu json si esto no es asi da null